# "Tu vas bien aimer ça" vs "Tu vas aimer bien ça"

Tags: sens

Les tournures ci-dessous ont-elles des sens différents ou peuvent-elles être utilisées de façon indifférente ?

> Tu vas bien aimer ça.

> Tu vas aimer bien ça.

Comment: Ça,  tu va bien aimer. spoken colloquial French.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La forme idiomatique est *Tu vas bien aimer ça*, l'autre n'est jamais utilisée.